# Render only one layer from texture 2D array

Tags: arrays, opengl, 3d, textures, layered

I have a Texture 2D array to layered rendering. I would like to know how to render only one layer from my layered texture.
I have a geometry shader who send different primitives to different layers and I would like to choose which layer to draw on the screen.

Comment: You are going to have to explain the situation/problem more clearly.

Comment: Layered rendering shouldn't actually display anything on screen. You have to draw into a layered FBO to do this, which means you'd have to later blit one of those layers to the default framebuffer to show it. If you want your geometry shader to just spit out data into a single one of those layers, that's what gl_LayerID is for. Set that one time and then emit your geometry, rather than multiple times.